# Fatal error: Class 'tx_some_extension' not found in class.t3lib_div.php on line 4856

Tags: php, caching, typo3

Sometimes it happens, that Typo3 gives creates an error in the Frontend after an extension has been updated:

Fatal error: Class 'tx_some_extension' not found in class.t3lib_div.php on line 4856

Answer (score 2):

This is due to some cache files not being deleted (I don't know when exactly this happens and why its not cleared by Clear all cache)...

Deleting the contents of `typo3temp/Cache/Code/` or the entire folder should solve this problem. Everything needed will be generated again with the next request.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a problem with permissions?
Additionally you should add the following to your typoscripts.ts

```
config.no_cache = 0
[globalString = ENV:HTTP_HOST=*yourdevdomain.com]
config.no_cache = 1
[global]
```

This prevents caching while you are working in your development environment.